# Django postgres connection, SET timezone for psycopg2

Tags: django, postgresql, django-3.1

In django settings.py I have `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tbilisi'`

I have same timezone for postgres also

and separately, both works correctly.

Though, in Django, when  I run raw queries like:

```
from django.db import connection
...
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select localtimestamp(0)")
res = cursor.fetchall()
```

This shows datetime with UTC time zone.

Probably this is caused by `psycopg2` connection settings? because this:

`print( connection.cursor().connection.get_parameter_status("TimeZone") )`

shows: `UTC`.

Question: How can I change this connection settings and SET needed timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue a `SET timezone TO 'Asia/Tbilisi';` query first, or set the [PGTZ environment variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) (using `os.environ` if you need to do it from python) before opening the connection. You can also issue an `ALTER DATABASE` or `ALTER ROLE` and set the timezone by default, as noted in the linked docs for `PGTZ`, but I tend to avoid that because it's easy to forget to do it for new DBs/users (& it also only applies for new connections; long-running ones will have the TZ that was the default when they connected).